# Combining DataFrames based on column labels DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, merge, split-apply-combine

I have weather data stored in many separate files where columns are for a particular measurement instrument and each row corresponds to the reading averaged over a particular day. Say one file looks like this:

```
first = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,3)), 
                     pd.date_range('1950-01-01', periods=10), 
                     columns=['A','B','C'])

first
Out[21]: 
                   A         B         C
1950-01-01  0.939932  0.504543  0.091025
1950-01-02  0.121418  0.725333  0.444813
1950-01-03  0.338385  0.783398  0.116468
1950-01-04  0.847905  0.846147  0.226074
1950-01-05  0.156315  0.704804  0.524886
1950-01-06  0.412284  0.425379  0.427246
1950-01-07  0.165859  0.406347  0.114586
1950-01-08  0.392670  0.789526  0.174001
1950-01-09  0.246180  0.776304  0.019368
1950-01-10  0.142213  0.731748  0.954076
```

And a second that looks like this,

```
second = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,3)), 
                      pd.date_range('1950-01-11', periods=10), 
                      columns=['A','B','D'])



second
Out[30]: 
                   A         B         D
1950-01-11  0.190767  0.905640  0.325411
1950-01-12  0.109964  0.754694  0.414402
1950-01-13  0.058164  0.305405  0.768333
1950-01-14  0.267644  0.919876  0.631083
1950-01-15  0.981333  0.454678  0.533075
1950-01-16  0.831600  0.823845  0.980366
1950-01-17  0.303585  0.091634  0.338517
1950-01-18  0.723445  0.088020  0.570779
1950-01-19  0.639665  0.954577  0.763810
1950-01-20  0.370629  0.716066  0.628383
```

I want to merge these two together so that all instruments (i.e., A, B, C, D, ...) can be shown in the same file with all of the measurement time periods. The expected result would look like this:

```
                   A         B         C         D
1950-01-01  0.939932  0.504543  0.091025
1950-01-02  0.121418  0.725333  0.444813
1950-01-03  0.338385  0.783398  0.116468
1950-01-04  0.847905  0.846147  0.226074
1950-01-05  0.156315  0.704804  0.524886
1950-01-06  0.412284  0.425379  0.427246
1950-01-07  0.165859  0.406347  0.114586
1950-01-08  0.392670  0.789526  0.174001
1950-01-09  0.246180  0.776304  0.019368
1950-01-10  0.142213  0.731748  0.954076
1950-01-11  0.190767  0.905640           0.325411
1950-01-12  0.109964  0.754694           0.414402
1950-01-13  0.058164  0.305405           0.768333
1950-01-14  0.267644  0.919876           0.631083
1950-01-15  0.981333  0.454678           0.533075
1950-01-16  0.831600  0.823845           0.980366
1950-01-17  0.303585  0.091634           0.338517
1950-01-18  0.723445  0.088020           0.570779
1950-01-19  0.639665  0.954577           0.763810
1950-01-20  0.370629  0.716066           0.628383
```

In order to get this I've tried:

```
first.merge(second, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[34]: 
                 A_x       B_x         C       A_y       B_y         D
1950-01-01  0.939932  0.504543  0.091025       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-02  0.121418  0.725333  0.444813       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-03  0.338385  0.783398  0.116468       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-04  0.847905  0.846147  0.226074       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-05  0.156315  0.704804  0.524886       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-06  0.412284  0.425379  0.427246       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-07  0.165859  0.406347  0.114586       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-08  0.392670  0.789526  0.174001       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-09  0.246180  0.776304  0.019368       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-10  0.142213  0.731748  0.954076       NaN       NaN       NaN
1950-01-11       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.190767  0.905640  0.325411
1950-01-12       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.109964  0.754694  0.414402
1950-01-13       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.058164  0.305405  0.768333
1950-01-14       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.267644  0.919876  0.631083
1950-01-15       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.981333  0.454678  0.533075
1950-01-16       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.831600  0.823845  0.980366
1950-01-17       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.303585  0.091634  0.338517
1950-01-18       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.723445  0.088020  0.570779
1950-01-19       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.639665  0.954577  0.763810
1950-01-20       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.370629  0.716066  0.628383
```

But as you can see the columns that need to be merged have been split because the there are no common row indices. I feel like this functionality would be a very useful addition to pandas. Can this be done?

Comment: `first.combine_first(second)`?  Although that potentially over-writes one dataframe with another, which may or may not be an issue.  Or maybe `first.append(second)`?  Correct answer may depend on whether could overlap and if so how you'd want to deal with it.

Comment: I think `combine_first` is actually exactly what I was looking for. Gives presence to calling frame but my data doesn't have any overlap. Seems like `combine' is the more flexible version as it allows for the use of a function to deal with conflicting cases.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a good characterization.  With no overlap I think `append` or `concatenate` would be the more common and straightforward way to do it, but I don't see any problem with using `combine` or `combine_first`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way is to use `.combine` function which will change the shape of the result to the union in both axis.

```
combiner = lambda x, y: np.where(pd.isnull(x), y, x)
first.combine(second, combiner)

                 A       B       C       D
1950-01-01  0.7917  0.5289  0.5680     NaN
1950-01-02  0.9256  0.0710  0.0871     NaN
1950-01-03  0.0202  0.8326  0.7782     NaN
1950-01-04  0.8700  0.9786  0.7992     NaN
1950-01-05  0.4615  0.7805  0.1183     NaN
1950-01-06  0.6399  0.1434  0.9447     NaN
1950-01-07  0.5218  0.4147  0.2646     NaN
1950-01-08  0.7742  0.4562  0.5684     NaN
1950-01-09  0.0188  0.6176  0.6121     NaN
1950-01-10  0.6169  0.9437  0.6818     NaN
1950-01-11  0.3595  0.4370     NaN  0.6976
1950-01-12  0.0602  0.6668     NaN  0.6706
1950-01-13  0.2104  0.1289     NaN  0.3154
1950-01-14  0.3637  0.5702     NaN  0.4386
1950-01-15  0.9884  0.1020     NaN  0.2089
1950-01-16  0.1613  0.6531     NaN  0.2533
1950-01-17  0.4663  0.2444     NaN  0.1590
1950-01-18  0.1104  0.6563     NaN  0.1382
1950-01-19  0.1966  0.3687     NaN  0.8210
1950-01-20  0.0971  0.8379     NaN  0.0961
```

Comment: Is this any different from `combine_first`?

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen this function before... So the function is replacing missing values in the first dataframe with those if the second?

Comment: Also it would be worth noting `combine_first`. The implementation looks a lot faster for large frames and should do the same thing with the function you are using

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `first` is `df1` and `second` is `df2`, using [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) appears to solve your problem.

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2])
                   A         B         C         D
1950-01-01  0.939932  0.504543  0.091025       NaN
1950-01-02  0.121418  0.725333  0.444813       NaN
1950-01-03  0.338385  0.783398  0.116468       NaN
1950-01-04  0.847905  0.846147  0.226074       NaN
1950-01-05  0.156315  0.704804  0.524886       NaN
1950-01-06  0.412284  0.425379  0.427246       NaN
1950-01-07  0.165859  0.406347  0.114586       NaN
1950-01-08  0.392670  0.789526  0.174001       NaN
1950-01-09  0.246180  0.776304  0.019368       NaN
1950-01-10  0.142213  0.731748  0.954076       NaN
1950-01-11  0.190767  0.905640       NaN  0.325411
1950-01-12  0.109964  0.754694       NaN  0.414402
1950-01-13  0.058164  0.305405       NaN  0.768333
1950-01-14  0.267644  0.919876       NaN  0.631083
1950-01-15  0.981333  0.454678       NaN  0.533075
1950-01-16  0.831600  0.823845       NaN  0.980366
1950-01-17  0.303585  0.091634       NaN  0.338517
1950-01-18  0.723445  0.088020       NaN  0.570779
1950-01-19  0.639665  0.954577       NaN  0.763810
1950-01-20  0.370629  0.716066       NaN  0.628383
```

Comment: I guess concatenating works in this simple case but when I tried this before with my actual data there were problems coming up where one dataframe contains no columns in the other and is of a different length... I will have to update the question to cover this case.